# Are the Professor Layton and the Curious Village download puzzles still available?

Tags: nintendo-ds, professor-layton-curious-village

I just recently bought Professor Layton and the Curious Village (EU version) to play on my 3DS.

It has a feature to download extra puzzles over the internet.

My question is, **are these puzzles still available?**

It's a bit of a pain to get the old DS games online because they only support WEP, so before I spend ages mucking about with networking, I'd like to know if it's even going to work, because the game originally came out in 2007 - maybe they took the extra puzzles offline by now?

Comment: EU or US version? I don't think *either* of them has been taken offline (the download is very small, and would rarely be hit at this point in time, so there's really no resources to be saved by removing it), but it might make a difference.

Comment: Good point, thanks, I have updated to indicate EU version.

Comment: From what I recall, the puzzles were on the cart and the download was just unlocking it.  Don't know if they've taken that server offline, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nintendo [very recently announced](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Wii/Setup-amp-Connect/Termination-of-Nintendo-Wi-Fi-Connection/Termination-of-Nintendo-Wi-Fi-Connection-859609.html) that the Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection service will be closing on May 20, 2014, and that this will affect all the DS Layton titles - after this date, the puzzles will no longer be available.

The link above is for Europe, but the same announcement has been made by [Nintendo of America](http://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/vyWpoM6CBIe6FjW8NIY7bvzOrgBURhzw). [Nintendo of Japan](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/support/information/2014/0227.html) announced the same date, but do not list the Professor Layton games as being affected - this is likely because Level-5 are publishing the games themselves in Japan, and Nintendo only lists the titles they publish. In other words, the Japanese version will most likely also be cut off at this date.

The answer is therefore *yes, they are still available* - but only for a little less than 3 months from now. After this, the only option would be to dump, modify, and re-upload the save data to the cartridge to unlock the puzzles that way.

Comment: A pity that they close the service.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely still up for EU servers so download while you still can.